# Create a new page via typed form-information

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having some issues with generating a new page on my server when the user has filled out some information via textfields.
I want it to save the information in a html file on my server, with the name of the html being taken from the title box. Is there any way I can copy the whole div onto a new page so that it stores it? I'm a complete newbie on this area, but hopefully someone has the time to help.

This is how my html looks:

```
<div class="form-style-10">
<h1>Create a new guide for others to view<span>Be specific and precise when creating your guide</span></h1>
<form>
<div class="section"><span>✔</span>Give your guide a name</div>
<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label>Please start with "How do" or "How to" <input type="text" name="title" /></label>
</div>
<div class="section"><span>✔</span>Step 1</div>
<div class="inner-wrap">
    <label><input type="text" name="field1" /></label>
</div>
<div class="section"><span>✔</span>Step 2</div>
    <div class="inner-wrap">
    <label><input type="text" name="field2" /></label>
</div>
 <div class="section"><span>✔</span>Step 3</div>
    <div class="inner-wrap">
    <label><input type="text" name="field3" /></label>
</div>   
 <div class="section"><span>✔</span>Step 4</div>
    <div class="inner-wrap">
    <label><input type="text" name="field4" /></label>
</div>   
<div class="section"><span>✔</span>Step 5</div>
    <div class="inner-wrap">
    <label><input type="text" name="field5" /></label>
</div>
<div class="button-section">
 <input type="submit" name="Sign Up" />
 <span class="privacy-policy">
 <input type="checkbox" name="field6">You agree to our Terms and Policy. 
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not attempt using PHP? when you get stuck show your PHP and we will help you from there.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a form using PHP. Here is a great tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp, make a new file using

`$newfile = fopen("example.html", "w")or die("Couldn't open file.");`

and write into it using

`fwrite($newfile, "Hello world!");`

By the way, don't forget to close the file using

```
fclose($newfile);
```

Hope I helped ;)